# Can't deploy a Discord.py bot successfully to Heroku which uses mongoDB to store data

Tags: python, mongodb, discord, discord.py, pymongo

This bot uses mongoDb to store data.
The same code is working fine in my pc, without any errors. and the data is being stored too

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient

token = open("token.txt", "r").read()
client = discord.Client()

mango_url = "mongodb+srv://TutorialBot:<password>@tutorialcluster-yywug.mongodb.net/test"
cluster = MongoClient(mango_url)
db = cluster["UserData"]

collection = db["UserData"]

@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print(f'{client.user} has connected to Discord!')
    
@client.event
async def on_message(ctx): 
  print(f"{ctx.channel}: {ctx.author}: {ctx.author.name}: {ctx.content}")
  if "python" in str(ctx.content.lower()):
    post = {"_id": ctx.author.id, "score": 1}
    collection.insert_one(post)
    await ctx.channel.send('accepted!')

client.run(token)
```

but, when i deply it to heroku, **there are no errors**, but the data is not stored at all.
following is the log in heroku.
[image: this is the log]

Comment: yeah you can't use mongodb in heroku [read this](https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/1823)

Comment: is that confirmed? can i use sqlite in heroku instead?

Comment: It is confirmed
`The mLab team has discontinued their MongoDB add-on. The mLab MongoDB add-on will be removed from all Heroku apps on November 10, 2020. Users should remove add-on instances attached to their apps via the Dashboard or the CLI.`

But idk about sqlite

Comment: You can try with [amazon aws free tiers](https://aws.amazon.com/) , [tutorial here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WE303yFWfV4)

Comment: You can use google Firestore which is a document db like Mongo. With the free tier you get 1 GB of data which is more then enough + You get 300$ credit in the first year to use as you like.

Comment: actually we just need to whitelist the ip addresses

Comment: we can use mongodb in heroku

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I could solve this issue myself.*

The problem which is stopping the script from **writing to mongoDB** database is that the **IP address** of heroku server.

I don't know the address correctly, so I used `0.0.0.0/0`(which simply means, allow modification requests from **any** IP address)

It is not **that safe** to allow from any IP address. But it is a good solution if your data is not a **big** secret.

To make this work,

1. go to [mongodb](https://www.mongodb.com)
2. login.
3. choose your project.
4. choose your cluster.
5. open network access from side bar.
6. click on add new ip address.
7. choose `allow from anywhere`(this will add `0.0.0.0/0`to the textbox)
8. give it a name.
9. hit enter.
10. give some time to process the changes.
11. Now run your script from any ip address, it should work. also you can deploy your script to **heroku**.